# How do you preload UIweb view?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My current load time for my application is pretty lousy, is there a way to preload a UIWeb view, I keep getting a white blank screen for like 15 seconds before the internal .html file is loaded into the UIwebview.

EDIT: ADDED MORE INFO BELOW:

For example, I am currently using:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Leadership" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

All the HTML is local, the pictures are within the application and the very little css there is are in the header of the html.

However, I don't think it is the actual HTML that is showing the white web view... I think that the application is very slow at loading the UIWebView class, because once the Webview is loaded on one tab, it is super fast on the other tabs, that use webview.

Comment: Check if any of these helps [1](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/14400-preload-webview.html) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307767/iphone-how-to-preload-a-local-file-in-a-uiwebview) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987074/preloading-a-uiwebview-avoiding-white-screen-flash) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973237/loading-the-content-of-a-uiwebview-before-displaying-it)

Comment: please describe what you mean by "internal .html file".  Is this a local resource in your app bundle?  If so, does this static html reference any content from the web (e.g. a stylesheet)?  If you can embed all your styles, script, etc, into the HTML file then it should load very fast.  Via some smart scripting, you can defer loading true web content (e.g. images) until after the page DOM has loaded.

Comment: and better yet, design your root view controller using native controls and assets loaded directly from your app bundle...

Comment: @CSmith It is a static page... and here is the code i am using... [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Leadership" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];

Comment: @CSmith However, I don't think it is the actual HTML that is showing the white web view... I think that the application is very slow at loading the UIWebView class, because once the Webview is loaded on one tab, it is super fast on the other tabs, that use webview.